# Symfony2 when should I create a new controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently using Symfony2 and and I'm trying to divide my code into different controller (like an Ajax Controller, a User Controller etc...) but I don't really know when I should use a create a new One.

For example my DefaultController is starting to be quite big (~800 lines) and I was wondering if having a too long controller could impact the website's performance? (Longer loading time...)
And, if it does, when should I split the controller into smaller ones ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that you should group your actions by which operate on the same data (entities) or operate within a well defined responsibility. E.g. UserController for users, PostController for blog posts, etc. This means that if you want to create an action which role is different than the rest of the actions, put it in a separate controller.

Symfony is caching almost everything so I don't think that huge controllers would cause an impact to the perfomance but if you have a thousands lines long controller, I'm not sure that it does only one thing.

The controller's size can be a warning sign too for the misplaced queries and business logic. You should separate QueryBuilder calls into Repository classes and other logic to services and event handlers. You can save more lines by using annotations instead of PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good idea to start with a controller for each relevant model, with a CRUD structure.

Of course it depends on your needs, but if you have a model "Post", you probably will need a PostController with CRUD routes and methods, like : index (/posts), new, update, create, delete... 
Depending what you need you can delete or add some method relative to a 
Post from this base structure.

Try to detect what is realy relative to a specific model in your defaultController and create a controller for it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What @riska and @Yoann said all holds true.

In addition, I prefer **not** to create separate controller if I'm sure that it hold only that one method. In that case, I just put it into `DefaultController`.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, controllers are the part of UI layer. If you care a lot about keeping your controllers small, let me give you the best scenario you can make what a controller must do:

```
1.Call the appropriate service
2.Return the response
```

That is 2 lines of code for each controller action, or you can even make it in one line.

Like person above said, controllers are usually separated by what type of entities / services they operate on. If you for example have an entity - lets say User, the following actions are most likely to be in there: createAction, editAction, removeAction, registerAction, activateAction, loginAction, logoutAction and so on...

It does not have any impact on performance if your controllers are thin or fat. The code will be executed in the similar flow, and all classes are being cached in the production environment.